# Object assignment using Implementation

Tags: java

I am trying to get to grips with interfaces and their implementation in Java.

I have an interface and 3 classes, 2 of which implement the interface. The implementation of the interface requires 2 methods,

- `toString()` *[which is using `@Overide` here for Netbeans satisfaction]* and
- `wheelCount()`.

  public interface IVehicle {
      @Override
      public String toString();
      public int wheelCount();
  }

We then have the two classes Bike and Car.

```
public class Bike implements IVehicle{
    @Override
    public int wheelCount() {
        return 2;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String s = "This is a Bike with " + wheelCount() + " wheels!";
        return s;
    }
}

public class Car implements IVehicle{
    @Override
    public int wheelCount() {
        return 4;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String s = "This is a Car with " + wheelCount() + " wheels!";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Some other class called `myClass` contains a method to print stuff out... `printStuf()`

```
public void prntStuf(IVehicle myVehicle){
    String s = myVehicle.toString();
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Assuming an instance of `myClass` is created, if somewhere in the code we create instances of `Bike()` and `Car()`, and we pass these objects into the method `prntStuf`, what would be the benefit in using either of these assignments.

***IVehicle x = new Car()***

```
    IVehicle modeoftransport1 = new Car();
    IVehicle modeoftransport2 = new Bike();
```

***As opposed to... Car x = new Car()***

```
    Car modeoftransport1 = new Car();
    Bike modeoftransport2 = new Bike();
```

Is there an actual difference or benefit or does it boil down to coding conventions?

From what I can tell, they both have the same effect, in that they both produce the same outcome. I've looked through previous questions on here and searched the web but can't put my finger on it. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Would you declare an Interface and then Instantiate an object with it in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716435/why-would-you-declare-an-interface-and-then-instantiate-an-object-with-it-in-java)

Comment: @MAK Thats my friend, didnt realise he was posting the question as well. Is it possible to merge or delete this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the type of the variable doesn't matter.

The choice of type is really a choice about what you're going to do with the variable later. When you say:

```
Car modeoftransport1 = new Car();
```

You're saying "I am going to be dealing with a new Car in ways where it matters that it's a Car"; for example, if Car had some other, Car-specific, methods, maybe you're going to call those. When you say:

```
IVehicle modeoftransport1 = new Car();
```

You're saying "I am going to be dealing with a new Car in ways where it doesn't matter what kind of vehicle it is".

So, yes, coding convention, or coding style, to a large extent.

Comment: Ok, so if I had a method called beep() in Car and wanted to call it later, yes I can see why I would use the former. I get this part now, as the former object can access beep() and the latter can only access methods specified by the interface. But why use the latter at all? Why would it ever make a difference.

Comment: Because you might want to say "I will definitely never want to call beep() on this". That might sound silly, but when you're working with large systems, the ability to omit details can be as useful as the ability to capture them. Are you at all familiar with Jorge Luis Borges? You might enjoy reading [Funes the Memorious](http://evans-experientialism.freewebspace.com/borges.htm).

Comment: @Tom I've been looking for a reasonable answer to this question and I think you've answered perfectly. Your comment was probably the most helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of this situation they are the same. If you had specific functionality in either of the derived classes, you would need to use the latter if you wanted to call that functionality later in processing when it is in scope (without casting).

Comment: Actually there's a difference even without any special functionality. Function overloads are resolved based on the static type of an object.

Comment: Thanks for adding that clarification. I would include overloading in specific functionality in my explanation.

Answer (score -1):

It does not matter in those statements, and is considered a BAD practice to use the latter.