# What is the difference between using different variable types to refer to the same object?

Tags: java, object, oop, inheritance

If I have a superclass named Vehicle and a subclass named SportsCar, what is the difference between these 2 codes to create an object of SportsCar? What would be the difference between car1 vs car2?

```
SportsCar car1 = new SportsCar();
Vehicle car2 = new SportsCar();
```

Comment: [Polymorphism](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Polymorphism&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: [chech this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/referencing-subclass-objects-with-subclass-vs-superclass-reference)

Answer (score 1):

I will explain it to you through an example:

Assume you had another subclass of `Vehicle` named `SUV`. Now, if you were to write a function that refuels vehicles. Since refueling remains the same for `SportsCar` and `SUV` you can have a function like :

```
void refuel(Vehicle vehicle){
   vehicle.refuel = true;
}
```

With the initialization like `Vehicle car1 = new SportsCar();`, and `Vehicle car1 = new SUV();`, you could easily call the function `refuel(car1); refuel(car2);`

The reason is simple, a parent class is a common reference for the various subclasses.

You can also have a look at this [common scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611908/why-do-you-assign-an-objects-to-an-interface) in the java world!!

You can also go through [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_polymorphism.htm) to understand the technicality of why it works in that way. And how is it an important pillar of OOP.