# No peek() method in LinkedList class?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, declaration

```
LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>(); // queue.peek()
Queue<String> queue2 = new LinkedList<String>();// queue2.peek()
List<String> queue3 = new LinkedList<String>(); // queue3.peek() error!
```

I declared the linklist class in three different ways. I know that the linkedlist class is the implementation of the queue and list interface, but when i declare in the third way and want to use the peek() method in eclipse, why there is a error? They are all the same class ?

Comment: You're trying to call `peek` on a variable of type `List`. The compiler doesn't care if it refers to a `LinkedList` or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a peek method in LinkedList class.

[`peek()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#peek()) is available in LinkedList class. Since you are using a reference of List type and List interface does not have method `peek()`, compiler wont allow you to call this.

In first two examples,you are using reference of [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) type,so you are able to call `peek()` method.

See [Why would you declare an Interface and then instantiate an object
   with it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716435/why-would-you-declare-an-interface-and-then-instantiate-an-object-with-it-in-jav)

Comment: so what is the difference of declaring the same reference(interface) with different classes? they all have the same methods?

Comment: see the link i have added..i hope it helps to understand why we use interface as a reference.

Comment: Explains the issue in clear, concise manner, and provides links to relevant information. +1. I've added an answer explaining the problem with an analogy and providing an example for using the method while maintaining the interface implementation, for anyone interested.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call methods specific of a ***concrete class*** from an instance of an ***abstract interface*** to it.

The relation between a `LinkedList` class and `List` interface is like the relation between a `Cat` class and an `Animal` interface:

Instances of `Animal` can call methods like `.breathe()` or `.reproduce()`, and respond to calls to these methods differently while the method itself remains the same (this is what interfaces exist for), but the interface should not have a `.sharpenClaws()` method, because not all animals have claws.

At which point, if you want to call the `.sharpenClaws()` method, you need to first ask *"but, which animal is this?"*

---

So, just like you would for the `Cat`'s `.sharpenClaws()` method (pseudo-code)...

```
if (animal is Cat) {
  //remove ambiguity by defining that the (animal) is a (Cat)
  Cat thisCat = (Cat)animal;
  //make the cat sharpen it's claws
  thisCat.sharpenClaws();
}
```

...To use the `LinkedList`'s `.peek()` method, you need to cast it back to the more specific class:

```
if (aList instanceof LinkedList) {
  ((LinkedList)aList).peek();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are declaring the `LinkedList` as List object.
The List interfaces doesnt offers the `peek()` method. 
Thats why you cannot use it.
see here [ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

Comment: pls explain the downvote..

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it's because your answer doesn't add anything the others don't have and just throwing a link to the Javadoc for List at the question probably won't help the person asking the question.

Comment: I do not know why downvote either.

Comment: Probably because it's only explaining the *"what"* without really explaining the *"why"*, and even at that, it's a crude explanation.

Answer (score -2):

[java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)
has no peek method. When you create your list using a `LinkedList<String>`, java internally casts it as a `List<String>` and so your peek method is lost.

The three objects you've created are *not* the same as they've been casted to different types.

Comment: The method is ***not*** lost. You only can't call it from the interface instance directly.

Comment: Also, *"When you create your list using a LinkedList<String>, java internally casts it as a List<String> and so your peek method is lost."* is a terribly misguiding way of wording what you're trying to say. Java is ***not*** *"internally casting"* anything. The code is explicitly doing the *"casting"* with `List varName = //...`.